# Why are solutions to $\sqrt[k]{x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+x_4^k}$ for $k=2,3$ curiously smooth?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, k3-surfaces

Given an integer solution $s_m$ to the system,

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2 = y^2$$

$$x_1^3+x_2^3+\dots+x_n^3 = z^3$$

and define the function,

$$F(s_m) = x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n$$

For $n\geq3$, using an *elliptic curve*, it can be shown there are an infinite number of primitive solutions. For $n=4$, we have *positive* and *primitive*,

$$\begin{aligned}
s_1 = 10,\, 13,\, 14,\, 44;\quad &F(s_1) = 3^4\\
s_2 = 54,\, 109,\, 202,\, 260; \quad &F(s_2) = 5^4\\
s_3 = 51,\, 65,\, 117,\, 159; \quad &F(s_3) = 2^3 7^2\\
s_4 = 99,\, 315,\, 797,\, 837; \quad &F(s_4) = 2^{11}\\
s_5 = 285,\, 371,\, 547,\, 845; \quad &F(s_5) = 2^{11}\\
s_6 = 815,\, 1297,\, 1781,\, 1939; \quad &F(s_6) = 2^3 3^6\\
s_7 = 259,\, 1307,\, 3485,\, 9349;\quad &F(s_7) = 2^6 3^2 5^2\\
\end{aligned}$$

with $s_6$ and $s_7$ found by MSE user oleg567.

***Questions*** (for $n=4$):

1. Why do these (apparently smallest) solutions have $F(s_m)$ as a [*smooth number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number)?
2. Is this really the complete list with all $x_i<10^4$? (These are the smallest if the list in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198002/) is appropriately complete.)

***Comment***: For $n=3,5$, small solutions do not necessarily have $F(s_m)$ that are smooth numbers.

> ***Edit***: Using $s_1$, we have,

$$P_k(x)=(\color{blue}{10}x^2 - x + 88)^k + (\color{blue}{13}x^2 + 68x + 28)^k + (\color{blue}{14}x^2 - 68x + 26)^k + (\color{blue}{44}x^2 + x + 20)^k$$

For $k=3$, it is already a cube,

$$P_3(x) = 45^3(x^2+2)^3$$

For $k=2$, it a *quartic* polynomial to be made a square with a rational point, hence an *elliptic curve*,

$$P_2(x) = y^2$$

with initial points $x = 68,\,165/94$, etc. *All* of the $s_m$ can be used in a similar quadratic form identity. Thus, after removing denominators, the system has an infinite number of integer solutions.

However, we are interested in the behavior of the small positive solutions and which seem to be knowable only by semi-brute force searching.

Comment: [there are an infinite number of _primitive_ solutions]-->what do you mean by "primitive" ?

Comment: If I didn't make any mistakes, this system of equations defines a rationally connected 3-dimensional projective variety. There's a decent chance that we can parametrize the rational solutions.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: We can define "primitive" as the $x_i$ do not have a common factor.

Comment: For $n=4$, maybe someone has a fast and efficient code to find all positive and primitive solutions with $x_i$ below a bound, say $x_i<10^4$. I am not yet 100% certain the list above is complete.

Comment: To me it also seems that the variety defined by Tito's equations is $3$-dimensional: it is a complete intersection of a quadric and a cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^5$, isn't it?

Comment: If remove restriction that $F(s_m)$ must be a perfect square (as in MSE), then list of $s_m$ for $k=2,3$ is much wider (sorted by $F(s_m)$):
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
s_1=\{10,13,14,44\};&F(s_1)=81=3^4\\
s_2=\{51,65,117,159\};&F(s_2)=392=2^3 7^2\\
s_3=\{54,109,202,260\};&F(s_3)=625=5^4\\
s_4=\{62,399,402,624\};&F(s_4)=1487\\
s_5=\{140,346,417,754\};&F(s_5)=1657\\
s_6=\{217,330,496,626\};&F(s_6)=1669\\
s_7=\{39,341,447,933\};&F(s_7)=1760=2^5\cdot 5\cdot11\\
s_8=\{104,399,632,760\};&F(s_8)=1895=5\cdot 379\\
s_9=\{19,117,711,1065\};&F(s_9)=1912=2^3 239
\end{array}
$$

Comment: $$
\begin{array}{rl}
s_{10}=\{78,521,658,680\};&F(s_{10})=1937=13\cdot 149\\
s_{11}=\{129,337,551,967\};&F(s_{11})=1984=2^6 31\\
s_{12}=\{285,371,547,845\};&F(s_{12})=2048=2^{11}\\
s_{13}=\{99,315,797,837\};&F(s_{13})=2048=2^{11}\\
s_{14}=\{273,353,579,939\};&F(s_{14})=2144=2^5 67\\
s_{15}=\{175,584,708,1052\};&F(s_{15})=2519=11\cdot 229\\
s_{16}=\{284,699,838,910\};&F(s_{16})=2731\\
s_{17}=\{170,659,712,1330\};&F(s_{17})=2871=3^2\cdot 11\cdot 29\\
s_{18}=\{137,410,586,1756\};&F(s_{18})=2889=3^3 107\\
s_{19}=\{220,444,903,1416\};&F(s_{19})=2983=19\cdot 157\\
\ldots
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Oleg567: Thanks. I had a feeling that the "smoothness" of small solutions might not remain if we remove the restriction that $F(s_m)$ be a perfect square.

Comment: @Oleg567 I have the impression that using the following restriction "either $F(s_m)=q^2$ or $F(s_m)=2q^2$", there are only solutions with smooth $F(s_m)$ so far. So it might be worth looking at that modified question.